# Javascript While Looping Through Array And Outputting in .innerhtml

Tags: javascript, html, while-loop

I'm brand new to Javascript and teaching myself.  I'm trying to setup a function that will write each of the elements of the array `AmericanCars` with a space between the elements.

I have it working so that when I use `.innerHTML=AmericanCars[Index Position]` plus a non-breaking space, I can write one element of the array.  Now I'm trying to loop through it with a `while` loop, but I just get an output of "undefined."

How can I get `.innerHTML` to write out each of the elements of an array with a space between them?  Is there a method that is simpler than using the While loop or is my While loop just formatted wrong.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>

        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        var AmericanCars=["Chevy", "Ford", "Dodge"];
        var JapaneseCars=["Honda", "Toyota", "Subaru"];
        var FavoriteCars=[];

        function ListAmericanCars() {

        var arraycounter = 0; 

        /* Use array counter to set the value that is displayed in innerHTML's square [] brackets */
            while (arraycounter <= AmericanCars.length) {

                document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = AmericanCars[arraycounter] + "&nbsp ";
                arraycounter++;
            }
        }
        </script>

        <p> What Are Your Favorite American Cars?  Answer: 
            <span id="content">______________
            </span>
        </p>

        <button onclick="ListAmericanCars()">
            American Cars Function
        </button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: very beautifully written post, well done!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays are 0-based. Change it to less than or else the last element will print undefined.

```
while (arraycounter < AmericanCars.length) {
    ...
}
```

Additionally, you could just do:

```
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = AmericanCars.join('&nbsp');
```

Comment: nicely explained! only one tiny thing missing: edit the last line so it appears as code (add 4 spaces)... ;)

Comment: .join was perfect and the simplest.  Also, I didn't need the nbsp.  I just put the space in as .join(" ").

Answer (score 1):

It's a bad idea. While you putting Data with `innerHTML`, the browser rendering it.

A better solution is to create an variable and append the data:^

```
var AmericanCars=["Chevy", "Ford", "Dodge"];
var JapaneseCars=["Honda", "Toyota", "Subaru"];
var FavoriteCars=[];

function ListAmericanCars()  {
    var arraycounter = 0; /* Use array counter to set the value that is displayed in innerHTML's square [] brackets */
    var myContent = '';

    while (arraycounter < AmericanCars.length) {
        myContent += AmericanCars[arraycounter] + "&nbsp ";
        arraycounter++;
    }

    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = myContent;
}
```

EDIT:
Ah forgotten. Dont use **<=** in your while loop. Thats not an valid index.

Comment: Thanks. What should I use for less than or equal to instead of <=

Comment: @AdrianPreuss You're not really explaining stuff, just plain say don't do this or that... Why is innerHTML bad...? Why use `<` rather than `<=`...? I think @codedigger explains it the best

Comment: Can you read? **the browser rendering it** directly if you put data over `innerHTML` into an element. You have very big troubles if you have more than a "small" array.

Comment: @AdrianPreuss Yes, dude, I can read, but can you read your own answer...? You write `It's a bad idea. While you putting Data with innerHTML, the browser rendering it.` - this is no explanation, sorry, also makes no sense at all...

Comment: @AdrianPreuss Additionally, `Dont use <= in your while loop. Thats not an valid index.` - again, this doesn't make sense, plus isn't true either: 1. `<=` is not an index, but an operator, and 2. it is valid! [have a read here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators)

Comment: its not valid because the the array is smaller than that!

Comment: @AdrianPreuss You should explain that in your answer, not in a comment, especially considering the asker is a beginner. They shouldn't just follow your lead because you say so, but should understand why...

Answer (score 1):

I think a `for` loop would more standard in this situation, also build up your content and then assign it to `innerHTML`. Array indexes start at `0` and not `1`, so you should use `<` and not `<=`', else you will be off by one at the end of your loop.

```
function ListAmericanCars() {
    var content = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < AmericanCars.length; i++) {
        content += AmericanCars[i] + "&nbsp ";
    }
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = content;
}
```

Comment: irrelevant. It does not matter, for which method you choose.

Comment: @AdrianPreuss agreed 100%

Comment: I voted up your post because I agree, but I thought it was worth showing that a `for` loop is more commonly used when looping over arrays.